# Dealing with multiple IDs in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/malleswar/sGfxV/)

I have multiple links and I want to have same hover effect on all the links, is there any simple way to do it. I wrote Javascript for one ID, but I don't want to write for all links.
When hovered, the link text should change to white and background color should change to red.

**CSS**

```
ul {
list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    margin-bottom:5px;
    width:100px;

}
ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;    
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div style='padding:10px;border:2px solid red'>
<ul>
            <li id='llist'><a href='#' id='list'>List</a></li>
            <li id='lgroups'><a href='#' id='groups'>Groups</a></li>
            <li id='lprofile'><a href='#' id='profile'>Profile</a></li>
            <li id='linvitations'><a href='#' id='invitations'>Invitations</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h5 style='color: white'>PROJECTS</h5>
        <ul>
            <li id='lsummary'><a href='#' id='summary'>Summary</a></li>
            <li id='ltrack'><a href='#' id='track'>Track</a></li>
            <li id='lmanage'><a href='#' id='manage'>Manage</a></li>
            <li id='lexport'><a href='#' id='export'>Export</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h5 style='color: white'>ANALYSIS</h5>
        <ul>
            <li id='lanalyse'><a href='#' id='analyse'>Analyse</a></li>
            <li id='lviewall'><a href='#' id='viewall'>ViewAll</a></li>
            <li id='lexport'><a href='#' id='export'>Export</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h5 style='color: white'>SETTINGS</h5>
        <ul>
            <li id='lusers'><a href='#' id='users'>Users</a></li>
            <li id='larchive'><a href='#' id='archive'>Archive</a></li>
            <li id='lsystem'><a href='#' id='system'>System</a></li>
            <li id='lmyprofile'><a href='#' id='myprofile'>My Profile</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#list').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).css('margin-left','10px');
            $(this).css('color','white');
            $('#llist').css('background-color','red');
        },function(){
            $(this).css('margin-left','0px'); 
            $(this).css('color','black');
            $('#llist').css('background-color','white');
        }

    );

});
```

**NOTE:**
Here I gave 'a' tag, may be it will become easy with a: hover, a: link etc. Also write the answer keeping in mind such that, it will be applicable to all.

Comment: Short answer : Dont work like that. use class instead. id should be unique.

Comment: You can use class to select multiple elements or simply use element tag as selector

Comment: Why didn't you use CSS `:hover`? I understand this question is tagged with `javascript` and `jquery` but still CSS will be the obvious choice since you also mention 'same hover effect on all links'.

Comment: I want to know the answer, if they are not links also.
see my NOTE

Comment: In that case use a class like '.pretty-hover', which along with '.pretty-hover:hover' can achieve what you need. Then you can apply this class to anything.

Comment: CSS only, no javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/sGfxV/18/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose the one you like

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list_items">
```

assign ul with class `list_items`

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.list_items li a').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).css('margin-left','10px');
            $(this).css('color','white');
            $(this).css('background-color','red');
        },function(){
            $(this).css('margin-left','0px'); 
            $(this).css('color','black');
            $(this).css('background-color','white');
        }
    );
});
```

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sGfxV/24/)

Better approach with js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.list_items li a').hover(

    function () {
        var x = $(this).parent('li');
        x.css({
            'margin-left': '10px',
                'color': 'white',
                'background-color': 'red'
        });
    },

    function () {
        var x = $(this).parent('li');
        x.css({
            'margin-left': '0px',
                'color': 'black',
                'background-color': 'white'
        });
    });
});
```

More Better Approach with classes

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sGfxV/26/)

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.list_items li').hover(

    function () {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    },

    function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

**css**

```
.active {
    margin-left:10px;
    color:white;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Or Just CSS approach

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sGfxV/28/)

```
ul.list_items li:hover {
    margin-left:10px;
    color:white;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `$(this).css('background-color','white');` you should use `$(this).parent().css('background-color','white');` because in his code `$('#llist')` is referred to the `li`

Comment: my background-color is applied to 'li' tag not 'a' tag. see my Fiddle once

Comment: Nice answer, but I would be tempted to ask you why you didn't suggest a css approach: `.list_items li a { ... } ` and `.list_items li a:hover { ... }` could do the trick without any Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

CSS-only solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/sGfxV/18/

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
    margin-bottom:5px;
    width:100px;
    background-color: white;
}

ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;    
    margin-left: 0px;
}

ul li:hover {
    background-color: red;
}

ul li:hover a {
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: white;
}

/* transitions for fun */
ul li,
ul li a {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
       -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
            transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a common string to each id and capture hover event on it. For example the common string is 'MyLink' and below code is to capture event on it. Make the changes in code as follows:

```
        <li id='llist_MyLink'><a href='#' id='list'>List</a></li>
        <li id='lgroups_MyLink'><a href='#' id='groups'>Groups</a></li>
        <li id='lprofile_MyLink'><a href='#' id='profile'>Profile</a></li>

    $('[id*="MyLink"]').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).css('margin-left','10px');
            $(this).css('color','white');
            $(this).css('background-color','red');
        },function(){
            $(this).css('margin-left','0px'); 
            $(this).css('color','black');
            $(this).css('background-color','white');

        }

    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this by pure css (don't need jquery or javascript)
here i've provide a solution with some modification in your code check below code
or check this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/sGfxV/19/

**CSS Code**

```
ul {
list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    margin-bottom:5px;
    width:100px;

}
ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    display:block;
    padding:0 0 0 10px;
}
.menu li a:hover{ color:#fff; background:red;}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div style='padding:10px;border:2px solid red'>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href='#' id='list'>List</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' id='groups'>Groups</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' id='profile'>Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' id='invitations'>Invitations</a></li>
    </ul>
        <h5 style='color: white'>PROJECTS</h5>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href='#' id='summary'>Summary</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' id='track'>Track</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' id='manage'>Manage</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' id='export'>Export</a></li>
    </ul>
        <h5 style='color: white'>ANALYSIS</h5>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li id='lanalyse'><a href='#' id='analyse'>Analyse</a></li>
        <li id='lviewall'><a href='#' id='viewall'>ViewAll</a></li>
        <li id='lexport'><a href='#' id='export'>Export</a></li>
    </ul>
        <h5 style='color: white'>SETTINGS</h5>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href='#' id='users'>Users</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' id='archive'>Archive</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' id='system'>System</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' id='myprofile'>My Profile</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: margin-left is missing

Comment: you should check code i've applied padding instead of margin @Lonely

Comment: But it is not applying when hovering, the hovered element should come right by 10px

Comment: @Lonely in my fiddle is working fine. and you are free to adjust css code according to you